# Calendar locale (German) for PlantUML gantt diagrams

Tags: plantuml

Can someone tell me, how I can define another calendar's locale (e.g. German) for the rendered calendar parts of the nice **gantt** feature in plantUML

I have something like:

```
@startgantt
-- Vorbereitung --
Project starts 2020-12-01
[Themenfindung] starts 2020-12-01 and ends 2021-01-01
[milestone] happens at 2020-12-15
-- ... --
@endgantt
```

The output prints month and daynames in English: [image: Output Gantt Diagram]

Is it possible at all and if so how can this be changed to German.

There is nothing about this in the documentation (https://plantuml.com/de/gantt-diagram).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With last beta http://beta.plantuml.net/plantuml.jar you can now specify a language for the Calendar.
For example:

```
@startgantt
Language DE
Project starts the 20th of september 2017
...
@endgantt
```

This will be integrated in next official release.

Answer (score 1):

According to their source code,
there are hardcoded values for days and months as [Enums](https://github.com/plantuml/plantuml/blob/cfa7591c4bc0a44a612348ef6837309ef42d973f/src/net/sourceforge/plantuml/project/time/DayOfWeek.java#L47)
and they use name() method to get their English names.
I would recommend you to clone their repo and change the hardcoded values in two classes:

1. In file `src/net/sourceforge/plantuml/project/time/DayOfWeek.java`
   replace method `shortName` like this:

```java
  public String shortName() {
    Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();
    String s = StringUtils.capitalize(java.time.DayOfWeek.valueOf(this.toString()).getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE, locale));
    return s.substring(0,2);
  }
```

2. In file `src/net/sourceforge/plantuml/project/time/Month.java`
   replace two methods like this

   ```
    public String shortName() {
    return StringUtils.capitalize(java.time.Month.valueOf(this.toString()).getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE,Locale.getDefault()));
   ```

   }

and

```
    public String longName() {
    return StringUtils.capitalize(java.time.Month.valueOf(this.toString()).getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL_STANDALONE,Locale.getDefault()));
}
```

I compile only these two classes and replace them in jar file. This works for me.

Mike.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best solution as you have to maintain your own copy / clone of plantuml and update to stay in tune with the official version. For a temporary solution it is OK but I think a better solution would be that the flexible way you propose would land into the official distribution. In the code there are a number of other places where the Locale is used, they have to be checked as well on consequences.

Comment: Yes, this is a temporary solution for the particular version of PlantUML v1.2021.6+ until these classes will not change. I need to compile only these 2 classes and it is not necessary to clone and compile the whole PlantUML project.